# Bootstrap rows outside panel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My bootstrap rows in my main page (and in modals) are going outside the panel container when the page extends beyond 1200px wide (lg).

I have created a fiddle here, however I can not find a way to make the fiddle wide enough to simulate large (over 1200px wide).

https://jsfiddle.net/bigalnz/f20rs3j8/13/

```
<body>
<div class="container">
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">REMOVED FROM</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-12" id="personSeizedFrom">
              <!--results here -->
              <div class="container"><div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10 font-weight-bold"><div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10">PERSON/Firstname/Middlename</div>
              <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10">Some Address, Any town</div>
              <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10">12/12/1980</div>
              </div></div></div></div>

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <!-- Button to Open the Modal -->
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#queryPersonModal">+ Person</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</form>
```

I have tried wrapping the rows in a parent  and also adding col-lg-10 to each col (along with the sm and md).

To illustrate what it looks like on my screen:

[image]

It would be nice to also get the button left aligned.

I have similar issues in other parts of the page so I am dong it wrong "globally".

Comment: are you using bootstrap 4?

Comment: Sorry if this sounds dumb, but would setting a `col-xl-` value make any difference.

Comment: @Saravana, according his fiddle he does.

Comment: we can check in fiddle over 1200px screen, there is no issue as per your image.

Comment: I was going to say... I'm viewing at 1470px and there's nothing that looks different than any other size, sparing the fact that the margin on the left side seems to widen as the page approaches it's next size breakpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap 4 `panel` class no longer available. I have used `card` to achieve the desired result.
In your code is working good but so much `row` and `column` used. Try with this simplified  code.

```css
.card-title {
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 0 0 8px;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <h3>REMOVED FROM</h3>
    <div class="card bg-light">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">PERSON/Firstname/Middlename</h5>
            <h5 class="card-title">Some Address, Any town</h5>
            <h5 class="card-title">12/12/1980</h5>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#queryPersonModal">+ Person</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @AlGrant I think first we let the user to validate the answer. If it is not suitable I will update based their requirement.

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap, rows have negative margin.
Try to replace

`<div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10 font-weight-bold"><div class="row">`

by

`<div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10 font-weight-bold"><div class="row m-0">`

to remove margin.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you way overdid the container/row/col nesting. Try something simpler like:

```html
<div class="container">
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">

            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">REMOVED FROM</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="container" id="wrapper-container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-12">PERSON/Firstname/Middlename</div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-12">Some Address, Any town</div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-12">12/12/1980</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#queryPersonModal">
                                    + Person
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

If you want that the content of the panel body is aligned with the heading, remove the `wrapper-container` block as `container` classes add extra padding left and right.

Comment: And yes as @Saravana mentioned `panel`s are now `card`s ;)

Answer (score 0):

I noticed your mark-up is not structured well,

```
please check this, this is the result you may want.
[https://jsfiddle.net/DayanandBotla/L1re6uzh/14/][1]

FYI....<br/>
Every col-XX will give padding-left and padding-right with 15px, you are seeing indent of it....thanks
```

https://jsfiddle.net/DayanandBotla/L1re6uzh/14/